# Calling a controller function from within a View laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, scope

Hi all I'm wondering how I might go about this...I am building a `laravel4` application and I would like to call a function in my `controller` that deletes all of the selected Items in the list.

This is my `view`

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Twitter Winners
            <div class="pull-right btn-toolbar">
                <a href="{{action('AdminBaseController@deleteSelectedTweets')}}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Selected</a>
                <a href="#"  class="btn btn-primary">Confirm Winners</a>
                <a href="#"  class="btn btn-primary">Generate New List</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                        <th>Tweet</th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>To</th>
                        <th>From</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                @foreach(Tweet::all() as $tweet)
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="delete_tweet" value="0"/></td>
                        <td>{{$tweet->tweet_text}}</td>
                        <td>{{$tweet->screen_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$tweet->name}}</td>
                        <td><select name="origin">
                                <option value="0">Origin...</option>
                                <option value="1">Station 1</option>
                                <option value="2">Station 2</option>
                                <option value="3">Station 3</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="destination">
                                <option value="0">Destination...</option>
                                <option value="1">Station 1</option>
                                <option value="2">Station 2</option>
                                <option value="3">Station 3</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Ideall I'd like to execute the `function` when the user selects this `link`:

```
        <a href="{{action('AdminBaseController@deleteSelectedTweets')}}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Selected</a>
```

I don't want to navigate away from the page and that is the only way I see being able to do it.

Comment: If that page can load up fast ( no much queries ), you could just write in that AdminController@deleteSelectedTweets function at the end return for same view. And your page will just refresh and do the job.

Answer (score 2):

That is an AJAX call you going to need.

E.g.

On click of the delete button:
- Get the selected items
- Add to AJAX data to be passed
- Call AJAX function (the function you reference)
- Remove items
- Update Dom.

There is too much code there to write on stack overflow, but suggest you look into your Jquery / Javascript side of things with some demos before jumping right in.

Comment: That's perfect, I will look into that so

Answer (score -1):

With Ajax you need:
- Controller function that does the job ex: AjaxController@deleteTweet($id)

Assume that you use post form to transfer selected tweets.

View:
First add 1 more class to each  tag.

```
<a href="{{action('AdminBaseController@deleteSelectedTweets')}}" tweet-id={{$tweetID}} class="tweet btn btn-danger">Delete Selected</a>


$(".tweet").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var tweetId = $(this).attr('tweet-id');
    var node = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: {{ route_to_ajax_controller }} + "/" + tweetId,
        success: function(data){
            node.remove();
        },
        error: function(error){
           console.log(error);
        }
    });

})
```

Ajax is best solution for this. In case you want to avoid Ajax, you can do something like this:

in AdminController

```
public function deleteSelectedTweets(){

// yours code

   return View::make("view-name"); // View from which you came here
}
```

This is easy solution, and your page should load fast, and you stay on same page.